# How to transit from a component to a route in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, query-string

I have a popup component in which i have a button and on click of that if im in my target route (mainRoute) i just want to pass the query parameters to my current route, but if i'm in another route i just want to transit with new query parameters. I know neither transitionTo or transitionToroute work. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `transitionTo` wouldn't work because you don't have access to routing from inside your component context. You can add the routing support at any place in your app using `-routing` service like so:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),
    someFuncUsingRouting(){
        let routing = this.get('routing');
        routing.transitionTo('some-route');
    }
});
```

Comment: The -routing service is currently private.

Comment: @Gaurav wasn't that you sitting in the same room with me when core-team member suggested to use this practice? :-)

Comment: Yes. That doesn't mean I don't warn people about using private stuff. I have seen the problems that can occur. It was Alex Matchneer who first showed me container.

Comment: @Gaurav That is reasonable! But since then i haven't came out to any better solution :( maybe you can suggest anything that would be better for the abstract case?

Comment: Bind a closure action down from the controller and call it on the component, @canufeel.

Comment: Thanks locks, i used an action from my current controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for logout function that close the session and redirect you to /login route.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    authManager: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    routing: Ember.inject.service('route'),
    tagName: '',

    actions: {
        invalidateSession() {
            console.log("logout invalidateSession");
            this.get('authManager').invalidate();
            let routing = this.get('routing');
            routing.transitionTo('login');
            }
    }
});
```

This is working code for:
ember-cli: 2.8.0
node: 7.1.0